# Dynamic Input fied and operations in Android

Tags: java, android, algorithm, android-fragments

I am kinda new in Android development. Now I know the use of fragments but stacked into a problem where I need to add more input fields on a fragment, When only the user requires in run time. Also I need to catch the value of that input field and calculate their values through the `MainActivity` and push it to another fragment of another Activity page.

I know how to collect data from fragment and push it through interface. what I need help of, how to add dynamic text field by click from user and how to get their value in calculation ?

elaboration :

Suppose there is two input field and one button, Now user want to add more input fields to add more to the input one, So I putted one plus button to it and when the user click on it one more input field will open. As this field is dynamic, how can I collect and add the data from that field into the calculation ?

Comment: do u try  to use a textView  with visibility = gone and when  your button clicked  make the TextView visible  and send text to activity ....

Comment: but it could be so many .. I mean user my need so many text field as per time, how can I track them ? As example, if suppose the user need the total run of the team and the number of teams may vary from 1 to 100 !

Comment: so you can use a listView .

Comment: Brother I think listview will not work, because What I want, I want to create as many of input field as may time user press the plus button and collect the input data by id or similar parameter so I can distinguishes them later. All this will happen dynamically in run-time.

Comment: please give me a example to I know what exactly you want .  a app or site or ...

Comment: thanks buddy! Actually this thing is kinda new maybe. I just want dynamically add more input fields during run time, I do not traverse from page to page like collecting how many text field yu need then generate it, I just want click a button and one more text field and take the value and consider it into calculation in java. Hope I could explain bro :)

Comment: so i think listView works for this case . you can hide or show listView and it items  and create layouts for each row of list.  suppose each row has a textView  and u have a button and when the Button clicked texts of all TextViews (input fields ) sends to activity or function or ... .